# Flutter Printing over WIFI

Tags: flutter, dart, printing

I am developing an app for school project using flutter and it should have a feature of printing a PDF document over WI-Fi (using WI-FI printers).

I didn't find any tutorials on printing using flutter so I want to know if flutter supports such thing and if not, is there a way around it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a printing package available for flutter here that might be what you need:

https://pub.dev/packages/printing

They even have example code that you can use:

https://pub.dev/packages/printing#-example-tab-

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?  If so, I'd greatly appreciate if you'd select the answer and give my answer an upvote. if not, please let me know how I can improve it.